# Datatable to Nullable<bool> with Automapper and DynamicMap Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, datatable, automapper

I have been scathing my head for a while now, I can't seem to get this to work.

Test classes:

```
public class SourceTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Int32 BVAL { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> BVAL { get; set; }
}
```

This works:

```
 SourceTest t = new SourceTest( );
 t.ID = 1;
 t.BVAL = 1;

 AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<SourceTest, DestinationTest>( );
 AutoMapper.Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid( );
 DestinationTest dest_test =  AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<SourceTest, DestinationTest>( t );
 bool? desttest = dest_test.BVAL; //true
```

This doesn't work:

```
DataTable tdt = new DataTable( );
tdt.Columns.Add( "ID", typeof( Int32 ) );
tdt.Columns.Add( "BVAL", typeof( Int32 ) );
tdt.Rows.Add( new object[] { 1, 1 } );

List<DestinationTest> t2 = AutoMapper.Mapper.DynamicMap<IDataReader, List<DestinationTest>>( tdt.CreateDataReader( ) );//Exception: {"Specified cast is not valid."}

 bool? bt = t2[0].BVAL;
```

It works however, if destination is like this:

```
public class DestinationTest
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> BVAL { get; set; }
}
```

That however naturally defeats the purpose.

Any ideas as to why Dynamicmap doesn't want to convert into nullable bool, while normal mapping works fine?

Edit:
I have tried various version of this code, but it doesn't work either:

```
private class NullBooleanTypeConverter : AutoMapper.TypeConverter<In32, Nullable<bool>>
    {
        protected override Nullable<bool> ConvertCore( Int32 source )
        {
            if ( source == null )
                return null;
            else
            {
                return source != 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

I almost make sure to tell Automapper about the converter before I try to convert:

```
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<Int32, Nullable<bool>>( ).ConvertUsing<NullBooleanTypeConverter>( );
```

If I try to debug, it seems that the converter is never used.

I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked the same questions at the github page: 
github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/454

It seems that there currently is no way to do it. The answer was this:

> Converters and resolvers aren't used in data reader maps, those go
>   through an entirely separate pipeline. Converting types isn't
>   supported in this version.

So there you have it.